# google spreadsheets api python - append content to a blank row

Tags: python, google-drive-api, google-sheets-api

i am doing an app with the google drive api, the finall step is to stake a bunch of data and append it to a existing spreadsheet, the problem is that when i append a row it is writed in the "A1" cell and it need to be writed in the following blank row e.i, not rewriting on the old data instead it have to write to a new blank cell

Answer (score 2):

You should look into sheets api instead, specifically `spreadsheets.values.append`.

[image: sample output]

Given the above, `spreadsheets.values.append` request will add new row/s of values after starting with row 3.

Detailed documentation should be [here](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/append).

Behavior and sample output of `spreadsheets.values.append` pasted above is discussed [here](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/samples/writing#append_values).